# running MQSC command against a specific installation

Tags: ibm-mq

In multi installation environment (of IBM MQ v9.0 on windows), I am trying to create a queue manager and set its installation (`crtmqm`, `setmqm`) from command prompt, but getting the error:

```
Command not executed from the installation named by the -n parameter
```

How do I perform the following actions:

1. check what the current installation associated with command
   prompt.
2. change the current installation associated with the
   command prompt ( basically running command against a specific
   installation, which is not necessarily the primary installation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your two questions:-

1. To check the current installation associated with the command prompt use the `dspmqver` command.
2. To change the current installation associated with the command prompt use the `setmqenv` command in one of the following ways:-

To set your installation you can either do so using the installation name, e.g.:-

```
setmqenv -n Installation2
```

or the path of the installation, e.g.:-

```
setmqenv -p c:\mqm8000
```

which has the same result as changing to the directory of the one you want and then telling it you want to change the environment to self (`-s`), e.g.

```
cd \mqm8000
setmqenv -s
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a command using non-primary installation,then you have to go to the installation(i.e bin) directory of the non-primary installation and then execute it from there.
If you want to set an environment then you have to use setmqenv. Following is the infocenter link which talks more about it

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083560_.htm

Comment: After you've run setmqenv of the installation you want to use, you can run the commands from anywhere, just like when using the primary installation.

Comment: Many thanks to you all, for the prompt response and pointing in the correct direction. Its working for me.